# PHP form POST shows as GET request

Tags: php, forms, post, get

I have a basic form for a survey (contains radio buttons and a couple hidden fields). The form submits to another PHP file that saves the answers for the current page, then redirects back to the survey (passing the next page via GET). This is accomplished using a header redirect.

Sporadically, different users are seeing an error while trying to save answers. This is because $_POST is empty. Each failed request shows that the page was requested with GET instead of POST, and the $_REQUEST variable is empty save for some cookie/session data.

I'm at a loss for what to look for next. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** My db shows that the answers were saved, and somehow after the form post, the page is hit again with GET and then fails (rather than redirect to the previous page).

**EDIT:**

Here's some of the code. Javascript from form page:

```
function nextPage(page,question_count)
{
    if (checkForm(question_count))
    {
        btn = document.getElementById('nextbutton');
        btn.disabled = true;
        gotoPage(page);
    }
}

function prevPage(page)
{
    btn = document.getElementById('prevbutton');
    btn.disabled = true;
    gotoPage(page)
}

function completeSurvey(question_count)
{
    if (checkForm(question_count))
    {
        frm = document.surveynav;
        frm.action = 'act_complete_survey.php';
        frm.submit();
        return true;
    }
}

function gotoPage(page)
{
    action = document.getElementById('gotopage');
    action.value = page;
    document.surveynav.submit();
    return true;
}

function checkForm(question_count)
{

    frm = document.surveynav;
    answer_count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++)
    {
        if ((frm.elements[i].name.indexOf('q_') > -1) && frm.elements[i].checked)
        {
            answer_count++;
        }
    }
    if (answer_count < question_count)
    {
        alert('Please answer all questions on this page before proceeding.');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


function openSurveyWin()
{
    window.open("survey.php", "surveywin", "location=0, toolbar=0, directories=0, status=0, menubar=0, scrollbars=0, resizable=0, fullscreen=0")
}
```

And HTML from the form:

```
    <form action="act_savestate.php" name="surveynav" id="surveynav" method="post">
                      <input type="hidden" name="gotopage" id="gotopage" value="" />
                <div class="question_holder"><div class="question">1 . Some question text here.</div><div><div style="padding-left:15px;"><input type="radio" name="q_1" value="1"  id="a_1" /><label for="a_1">Strongly Disagree</label><br />
    <input type="radio" name="q_1" value="2"  id="a_2" /><label for="a_2">Disagree</label><br />
    <input type="radio" name="q_1" value="3"  id="a_3" /><label for="a_3">Neither Agree nor Disagree</label><br />
    <input type="radio" name="q_1" value="4"  id="a_4" /><label for="a_4">Agree</label><br />
    <input type="radio" name="q_1" value="5"  id="a_5" /><label for="a_5">Strongly Agree</label><br />
    </div></div></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="questions" id="questions" value="1,10,19,28,37,46,55,64,73,2,11,20,29,38,47,56,65,74,3,12" />
<input type="button" id="nextbutton" name="nextbutton" value="Next &gt;&gt;" onclick="nextPage(2,20);" />
    </form>
```

And code from act_savestate.php:

```
$gotopage = isset($_POST['gotopage']) ? (int)$_POST['gotopage'] : 1;
if (!isset($_POST['questions'])) {
// No post
  die("No questions included");
}

$questions = explode(',',$_POST['questions']);

foreach($questions as $questionid)
{
    if (isset($_POST['q_' . $questionid]))
    {
        $survey->setAnswer($survey_id,$questionid,$_POST['q_' . $questionid]);
    }
}

header("Location: survey.php?page=$gotopage");
die();
```

Comment: Look for some malformed HTML suggesting that your form action is not being set to POST- perhaps you have a stray form tag or similar in your page code? That would be the first avenue I would explore.

Comment: A bit of code would help. Check the method property of your `form` tag, or use the `isset()` function to verify your $_POST variable are set.

Comment: The errors happen before or after the redirect?

Comment: @glenatron - The HTML isn't malformed from what I can tell, the only errors upon validation are missing attributes for <html> and <script>.

Comment: @Shaowxvii - I'm checking in the file specifically for $_POST['key'], but the post is empty. I'm only using $_REQUEST to log when the error happens to see what's contained within.

Comment: @void - it would appear upon digging deeper that the form is submitting correctly but redirecting back to the same file via GET.

Comment: @user1449253 You may provide us some code of the form page and action page ?

Comment: @void I edited the question to include code.

Comment: @Shadowxvii - any more input after seeing the code? Thanks everyone for the suggestions.

Comment: This issue is still plaguing me, and is pretty critical. Any other input/suggestions are highly welcomed!!!